# Extracting "faulting process id" from Application log

Tags: powershell, event-log

I cannot find a way to pull out the "faulting process ID" from the application log using Powershell or WMI.  The following returns the error, but for some further code, I need the actual PID, not the application name.  Can this be done?

```
Get-EventLog application 1000 -entrytype error -newest 5 | Select-Object  timegenerated,message,@{name='Executable';expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}}
```

Comment: The PID is only logged in the Message, so you'd need to grab the Message property and use something like regex to capture "Process ID:* \rn"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a start with RegEx (named capture group)

```
$log = Get-EventLog application 1000 -entrytype error -newest 5 | 
  Select-Object  timegenerated,message,@{name='Executable';expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}}
$log | %{
  if ($_.message -match '(?smi)Faulting process id: (?<PID>0x[0-9a-f]+)'){
    $_.Executable,$matches.PID
  }
}
```

I'd put that into a table / noteproperty, for me it's to late today.